# proc tabulate output not in alphabetical order

Tags: sas

original output

```
                 Count 
            AAB          BB
01NOV2014   5            4
02NOV2014   4            3
```

But ideal output is

```
                 Count 
            BB          AAB
01NOV2014   4            5
02NOV2014   4            4
```

Is there a way to change a n by k tables from `proc tabulate` to list it as requested?

Since k is not small, I'm looking for an efficient way to achieve this. Maybe store the requested order in a macro variable?

Comment: please share your code - what have you tried so far?

Comment: In this case this is a pretty direct question, with a straightforward answer - I don't really think code is required (the PROC TABULATE that generates that table is trivial after all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest answer depends on how the order is derived.

You have some ordering options on the `class` variable, such as `order=data`, which may give you the desired result if the data is stored in that order.  This can be tricky, but sometimes is a simple method to get to that result.

Second, you have a couple of options related to formats.

- If the data can be stored as a formatted numeric, where `BB=1`, `AAB=2`, etc., then use `order=unformatted` to achieve that.
- Create a format that lists the values in order, just formatting them to themselves, with `notsorted` in the options of the value statement, and then use `order=data` on the class statement and `preloadfmt`.

Example of the second option:

```
data have;
input var $ count;
datalines;
AAA 1
AAB 2
BBA 3
BBB 4
;;;;
run;

proc format;
 value $myformatf (notsorted)
  BBB=BBB
  AAB=AAB
  BBA=BBA
  AAA=AAA
  other=' ';
quit;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class var/order=data preloadfmt;
  format var $myformatf.;
  var count;
  tables var,count*sum;
run;
```